# PHP/MongoDB: find() is ignoring timeout setting

Tags: php, mongodb, timeout

Trying mongodb global timeout etc. is still ignored by find() queries in my PHP script.
I'd like a findOne({...}) or find({...}) lookup and wait max 20ms for the DB server before timeout.

How to make sure that PHP does not utilize this setting as soft limit? It's still ignored and processing answers even 5sec later.

Is this a PHP mongo driver bug?

Example:

```
MongoCursor::$timeout=20;
$nosql_server=new Mongo('mongodb://user:pw@'.implode(",",$arr_replicas).'',array("replicaSet" => "gmt","timeout"=>10)) OR troubles("too slow to connect");
$nosql_db=$nosql_server->selectDB('aDB');
$nosql_collection_mcol=$nosql_db->mcol;
$testFind=$nosql_collection_mcol->find(array('crit'=>123));
//If PHP considered the MongoCursor::$timeout, I'd expect the prev. line to be skipped or throwing a mongo/timeout exception if DB does not return the find result cursor ready within 20ms.
//However, I arrive with this line after seconds, without exception whenever the DB has some lock or delay, without skipping previous line.
```

Comment: Are you setting timeouts in your php.ini config, or in code? Either way, can we see what code you are using to do the find?

Comment: I set the timeout within the script. Edited: You can find the example code now.

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP documentation for [$timeout](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.timeout.php) the following is the explanation for the cursor timeout:

> Causes methods that fetch results to throw a
>   MongoCursorTimeoutException if the query takes longer than the
>   specified number of milliseconds.

I believe that the timeout is referring to the operations performed *on* the cursor (e.g.  `getNext()`).

Answer (score 0):

Do not do this:

```
MongoCursor::$timeout=20;
```

That is calling a static method and won't do you any good AFAIK.

What you need to realize is that in your code example, **$testFind** *is* the MongoCursor object. Therefore in the code snippet you gave, what you should do is add this after everything else in order to set the timeout of the **$testFind** MongoCursor:

```
$testFind->timeout(100);
```

NOTE: If you want to deal with **$testFind** as an an array you need to do:

```
$testFindArray = iterator_to_array($testFind);
```

That one threw me for a loop for awhile. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention on the readPreference attribute. The possible values are:

```
MongoClient::RP_PRIMARY
MongoClient::RP_PRIMARY_PREFERRED    
MongoClient::RP_SECONDARY
MongoClient::RP_SECONDARY_PREFERRED 
MongoClient::RP_NEAREST
```